# Make a backup everyday and save the file(s) seperatedly folders by month's name

Tags: linux, bash

I want to backup my website on my VPS with cronjob x3 in a day and make directories seperatedly by month's name and create 1,2,3,4 directories (these are the "weeks" in a month) and save the files in those directories which matching for example:

today is 24th November ... then the script is creates a directory named November and creates another directory in the November directory named 1 (this is the first week) and moves the tar.gz file from my www root folder in that folder. I can create directory with current month's name and moving the tar.gz file from my www root folder with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir "$(date +%B)"
cd /var/www/html/
mv backup.tar.gz /root/backups/"$(date +%B)"
```

But how can I do the weeks part (1,2,3,4 folders) so how the cronjob knows when needed to create those folders and where to move the files?

Comment: `I do the weeks part (1,2,3,4 folders)` The weeks are like weeks in the month? So like day of month divided by 7 plus 1?

Comment: Thanks, you are so kind but I found something which counts the current date's week-day: `$((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))` now I'm try it out

Comment: That's exactly what I proposed....

Comment: FYI, in order to make it easier to traverse your directory structure in the future, you should create directories like this:  `year` / `month` / `day`.  Ex: `2021/11/24`.  This way your files will always be sorted correctly.  Or `year` / `month` / `week in the month`.

Comment: How will you account for months with 5 weeks?  Like this current November.  Weeks do  not start on the 1st.  It would be simpler to store backups for each day (since you have 3 backups per day, it is going to be a lot files fast), or use the week number that `date +%U` provides.